# how to containerize a laravel application with one dockerfile?

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile

I have a laravel application which i would like to run into a docker container in one dockerfile (in fact i use kubernetes as orchestrator so docker-compose as i saw in many tutorial is not adequate in this case).
here is my dockerfile :

```
FROM alpine:3.11
# Set up environment variables
ENV DB_CONNECTION=mysql
ENV DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
ENV DB_PORT=3306
ENV DB_DATABASE=laravel
ENV DB_USERNAME=root
ENV DB_PASSWORD=

# Install packages
RUN apk --no-cache add php7 php7-fpm php7-pdo php7-pdo_mysql php7-json php7-openssl php7-curl \
    php7-zlib php7-xml php7-phar php7-intl php7-dom php7-xmlreader php7-xmlwriter php7-ctype \
    php7-session php7-mbstring php7-gd php7-fileinfo php7-tokenizer nginx supervisor curl

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

#ENV PATH "$PATH:/usr/local/bin"

# Configure nginx
COPY nginx-php/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Configure PHP-FPM
COPY nginx-php/php-fpm.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY nginx-php/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/custom.ini

# Configure supervisord
COPY nginx-php/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Setup directories
RUN mkdir -p /var/www
RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx

# Copy the app into document root
# Irrelevant in the dev environment (because of mounted volume), necessary for production
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY . /var/www


# Install composer dependencies
RUN composer update 

RUN composer install

# Copy .env.example to .env
RUN cp /var/www/.env.example /var/www/.env

# Make sure files/folders needed by the processes are accessable when they run under the nobody user
RUN chown -R nobody.nobody /var/www && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /run && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/lib/nginx && \
  chown -R nobody.nobody /var/log/nginx

# Switch to use a non-root user from here on
USER nobody

# Expose the port nginx is reachable on
EXPOSE 8080

RUN php artisan key:generate

#RUN php artisan make:migration my_first_migration

RUN chmod 777 start.sh

#ENTRYPOINT [ "/var/www/ php artisan migrate" ]
# Let supervisord start nginx and php-fpm
CMD ["sh","/var/www/start.sh"]
```

and my start.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
php artisan migrate
/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

when i run docker run i get this error :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|
```

the laravel application is running but the migration is not working.

Note : my container is trying to connect to a mysql database.

here is my .env :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: 2 things; first, never run `php artisan key:generate` because if you have a load balancer or whatever, the key must be the same, else you are going to have massive issues. Second, if the database is being created and run before this happens or at the same time, the answer is, the database is not ready, so you are trying to connect to a database. What I would say is NEVER run a `php artisan` command on an image creation or have that part of the image startup... you only migrate when you need it, not on the image initalization... that is not good, have it as an OS thing to do, not docker image

Comment: `DB_HOST` and `REDIS_HOST` need to refer to the host machine IP which (typically) is 172.17.0.1 . Also it is not generally good practice to have one container to run multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In 3 steps this is my solution:

### 1. Dockerfile

```ini
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql zip


# Copy Laravel app files
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set write permissions to used folders
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

# Change working directory to Laravel app root
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install composer and Laravel dependencies with composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

# Expose port 80 for Apache
EXPOSE 80
```

Somethings to notice:

- Nginx is a no go. It can't interpret PHP. Nginx needs a complementary container to intepret the language.
- You can setup your environment variables how you like.

### .htaccess file

Using this Dockerfile you will also need a .htaccess file like so to make it work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This file needs to by at the root of your project. Apache by its own won't detect your public folder. The .htaccess file will redirect Apache to your public folder.

### .dockerignore file

A .dockerignore

```
.git
.env
```

This will ignore your .env file and your .git files.